# Pentaho Kettle 8 Kafka Consumer

Tags: apache-kafka, pentaho, kettle

I'm having some issues when I use the new Kafka consumer connector. I use it as documentation says, I have the connector alone in a transformation and I have a transformation following this one in a job, with a get records from stream step.

The problem is that the first transformation, with kafka consumer, never finishes, and it's always running, without receiving nothing.

Answer (score -2):

Follow me, like below screenshot:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: StackOverflow is very focused on an inclusive community. Please assume that severly seeing-impaired users only get the screen reader version of your answer. For them, your answer is completely free of any helpful information. Those who can see will not enjoy the large areas of no information in your suboptimally cropped pictures either. Also, please, if the system says "enter image description" fives times. Then please take the hint. It might actually end up making sense to screen readers. Even for the seeing with giant screens (like me), an explanation would be nice.