# How to use Kafka consumer in pentaho 8?

Tags: apache-kafka, pentaho, kettle, consumer

I tried to use new Kafka consumer step of pentaho kettle 8, but I'm not able to load any data. When I use it, it's always like reading, but i can't see any data.

There is any tutorial or some example of how to read data? I saw that official documentation it's not very useful, it's not well explained, and i didn't find any example on the net.

Thank you in advance,

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pentaho Kettle 8 Kafka Consumer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47828680/pentaho-kettle-8-kafka-consumer)

Answer (score 2):

I have a working transformation and sub transformation, The changes we did are,

## In the kaka transformation,

1.We are using direct bootstrap server on connection.
2. we added the consumer group "cons1"
3. Changed the auto.offset.reset    to "earliest" on options tab.

## In the sub transformation.

In "Get records from stream" step, we gave the below fields
Fieldname   Type
key None
message None
topic   None
partition   None
offset  None
timestamp   Timestamp

## Kafka Version: kafka_2.11-1.1.0

I uploaded a sample .ktr that works
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1mr1ZYU_A0uAedRdgRs2oDF6HubOO4UPx/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

Check the kafka configuration file : server.properties
set advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://your.host.name:9092
Otherwise remote access is not possible